# A question in rails db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now , I execute the command line "rake db:migrate" on the window OS, but I got the problem in the console. it print `couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding`~/.ruby-uuid'`
who can help me to solve this ?  Thank you and best regards!

I think i should add the home path in the window environment . but i don't know ,which folder should i specify add in the $home path? anyone can tell me the specific folder of the home path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on My Computer > Advanced tab > Environment variables button, add a new variable called HOME with the full path to your home folder.

welcome to your first of many problems with gems that are not tested with windows. in unix systems, HOME is always defined, and files that start with . are invisible. apps create . files in your home directory to store user specific settings all the time.

unfortunately, a very small percentage of ruby devs use windows for dev work, which is why most people either recommend getting a mac, or installing linux

Comment: Thank you for your clear reply! I am using the linux OS for dev work. but sometimes i must deploy the project on window OS, so i encounter some question.

Comment: Can you tell me the specify folder name of the home path?